# Error on eclipse java oxygen with java.lang.NullPointerException message

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I get this message as soon as I create an android test project on eclipse.
I've been reading `Android game programming for dummies`, I followed every step yet I still get this same error.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Hello World'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

[This is a printscreen of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STMKK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch workspace

File -> Switch Workspace  or

In the create project wizard. don't create an activity in the wizard. just untick create an activity (Select No Activity) and just create the activity manually in the Android Manifest as

```
   <activity
         android:name="com.example.helloworld"
 android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: I did what you said I should do but I still get the same error.